# how to check if the token generated is valid or not

Tags: angular, jwt

I am using the website 'https://reqres.in/api/login' for authentication and canActivateGuards.
However when i am trying to access the token I am getting error as :
**core.js:6185 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The inspected token doesn't appear to be a JWT.**

my code for checking token is as follow:

```
public isAuthenticated():boolean{
  var token=(sessionStorage.getItem("currentUser")?JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("currentUser")).token:
  null)
  //console.log(token)//printing the value of desired token.




  if (this.jwtHelperService.isTokenExpired(token))
  {
    return false;
  }
  else{
    return true;
  }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What does the token look like in the console output?

Comment: {"token":"QpwL5tke4Pnpja7X4"}   it looks like this

Comment: that's not a JWT, therefore the errormessage is correct.

Comment: @jps can you pls throw more light

Comment: @jps the website i have referred to returns this token only

Comment: That is not a valid JWT. You could manually check the contents of a JWT here: https://jwt.io/

Comment: @Rini: JWT is a certain token format (see [here](https://jwt.io/introduction/)), but not every authorization token used in the web is a JWT. And the one you show is certainly not. Knowing this, using the jwtHelperService won't help. And for most other token types there's no easy way to inspect them, as there's no readable content.

Comment: ok.got it..thanks everyone for all  help